# How to insert values inside array of array elements in json using json ?Or How to insert values in this below json string

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp

```
queryString = {
  dynInfo : [ {
      dynamicIdQuestionAnswers:[{divid:'',question:'',answer:''}]
  }]
};
```

This is the Query string. Here `dynInfo` and `dynamicIdQuestionAnswers` are both arrays.
How do I insert the elements inside the `dynamicIdQuestionAnswers` array?

Here is what I am trying now. Is it also possible to have array of array in json string?

```
totalIndex=0;
queryString.dynInfo = [];
queryString.dynInfo.push({});

for(var r=0;r<dynamicQuestionIndex;r++){
    queryString.dynInfo.dynamicIdQuestionAnswers = [];
    queryString.dynInfo.push({});
    queryString.dynInfo[totalIndex].dynamicIdQuestionAnswers[r]['divid'] = "someText";
    queryString.dynInfo[totalIndex].dynamicIdQuestionAnswers[r['question'] = "someText";
    queryString.dynInfo[totalIndex].dynamicIdQuestionAnswers[r]['answer'] = "someText"
}
```

dynamicQuestionIndex is having  some value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I insert the elements inside the dynamicIdQuestionAnswers array?

**Sample code**

```
var dynamicQuestionIndex = 3;

var queryString = {};
queryString.dynInfo = [];
queryString.dynInfo.push({});
queryString.dynInfo[0].dynamicIdQuestionAnswers = [];

for (var r = 0; r < dynamicQuestionIndex; r++) {
    queryString.dynInfo[0].dynamicIdQuestionAnswers.push({
        divid: "someText",
        question: "someText",
        answer: "someText"
    });
}

$('c').append('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(queryString, undefined, 2) + '</pre>');
```

**Result**

```
{
    "dynInfo": [{
        "dynamicIdQuestionAnswers": [{
            "divid": "someText",
            "question": "someText",
            "answer": "someText"
        }, {
            "divid": "someText",
            "question": "someText",
            "answer": "someText"
        }, {
            "divid": "someText",
            "question": "someText",
            "answer": "someText"
        }]
    }]
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/3KKBr/1/

Comment: queryString = {
  dynInfo : [ {
      dynamicIdQuestionAnswers:[{divid:'',question:'',answer:''}]
  }]
};  This is defined in all java script file . so that i can use it from one jsp to another jsp . the solution you have gave is amazing.But it is not storing in another page jsp .  the other values in json string is flowing across all jsp pages .But i need this to be values to be stored in json across all jsp pages